# Crystal Reports Enterprise parameter is read only

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

I am attempting to edit a Crystal Report Enterprise version 4.3 report, and allow a parameter to accept multiple values. The problem is that the parm is set to Read Only, and I do not see a way to change that. I was able to create a new multi-value parm, but it does not let me delete the original. This is an old software, but it is what I have to use. I need to either be able to check the box for multiple values or delete this parameter and use the new one. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an "inherited parameter". These are created, for example, at the command level and can only be edited where they were created. You will likely find this parameter in a command object when you open the Database Assistant in Crystal Reports.

> Parameters can also be created at universe level or in query panel and they can be later inherited into Crystal Reports. They are called inherited parameters. These parameters can be dropped at the report level but they can’t be edited in a report. These parameters can only be edited where they are created.

Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/crystal_reports/crystal_reports_parameters.htm